# AVCapture session Failed while recording screen

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I created the command line utility for Mac OSX using AVFoundation's capture session to record the screen. I got this error when I tried recording the screen.

Error: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11844 \"Cannot Capture\" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7feff1753d70 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-67393 \"(null)\"}, AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey=false, NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Capture, NSLocalizedFailureReason=There was an unexpected problem with the graphics sub-system that prevented screen capture.}

Please, someone, help me to understand this error more. Is there way to resolves this? It occurs randomly

Comment: Can you add breakpoints to your code and find the line that's causing the crash and upload all relevant code so we can help.

Comment: @Jake Please check the code and another issue in the below link 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49051467/audio-output-is-not-working-after-the-screen-recording-using-avcapture-session

Comment: @SureshKumarS what ended up being the answer to this problem?